# Does tablockx have to been specified in each session?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two test transactions in two session respectively. Assuming these two transaction will run simultaneously. What I attempt to do is to let one transaction insert invoice number correctly after the other transaction is done. No duplicate. I did it as below. But if I remove with (tablockx) in session 2, they won't work any more. I checked on line book but no answer. Anybody would help? Serializable won't work since two SELECT want to be exclusive to each other here. Thanks.

In session 1:

```
begin transaction 
    declare @i int
    select @i=MAX(InvNumber) from Invoice 
    with(tablockx) 
    where LocName='A'
    waitfor delay '00:00:10'
    set @i=@i+1
    insert into Invoice values('A',@i);
commit
```

In session 2:

```
begin transaction 
    declare @i int
    select @i=MAX(InvNumber) from Invoice 
    with(tablockx) 
    where LocName='A'
    set @i=@i+1
    insert into Invoice values('A',@i);
commit
```

Answer (score 1):

That will work but also completely block all other access to the table.

You can potentially lock at a lower granularity (than table) and mode (than exclusive) if you do `WITH(UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK)`.

`HOLDLOCK` gives serializable semantics so can just lock the range at the top of the index (if you have one on `LocName,InvNumber`).

`UPDLOCK` ensures two concurrent transactions can't both hold the same lock but, unlike exclusive, doesn't block other (normal) readers that aren't using the hint.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

DECLARE @i INT

SELECT @i = MAX(InvNumber)
FROM   Invoice WITH(UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK)
WHERE  LocName = 'A'

WAITFOR delay '00:00:10'

SET @i=@i + 1

INSERT INTO Invoice
VALUES     ('A',
            @i);

COMMIT
```

Alternatively you could just use [`sp_getapplock`](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/application-locks-or-mutexes-in-sql-server-2005) to serialize access to that code.

Comment: (UPDLOCK,HOLDLOCK) doesn't work since same invoice number is generated for two session.

Comment: @FebWind - If you are running it inside a transaction as my answer this is not possible. `HOLDLOCK` always locks at least the entire range specified by the query and it is not possible for two concurrent transactions to have an `UPDLOCK` on the same resource.

Comment: @FebWind - And this is easy to see in SSMS. Just open two windows. And execute the following in both `BEGIN TRANSACTION DECLARE @i INT SELECT @i = MAX(InvNumber) FROM   Invoice WITH(UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK) WHERE  LocName = 'A'` the second transaction will be blocked "executing query" waiting on the first until you go back to the first window and execute either `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK`